# Using symbolic link inside web server root

Tags: linux

Can I create one folder inside my web server root and then create one symbolic link(soft link) for that folder anywhere in disk so that whenever I refer this folder in my pages ,server will actuaaly look for files in disk.Is it a violation of web server security ? Please suggest if it is possible to achieve the same differently.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on webserver and configuration. In Apache, for example, you can control if symlinks are allowed with the FollowSymLinks configuration option.

More on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html

Answer (score 1):

As per server security it is not recommended, but you can configure your web server for this. steps are given below

1. Allow FollowSymLinks (apache) configuration
2. Allow proper permission on folder and files to web server (apache)
3. make sure that path fall under "script handler's" allowed path (php.ini => open_basedir)